select text between quotes in vscode
Yes, I know the combination "shift+alt+right" (Expand Selection).
But it selects text WITH the quotes.
I want just the text.
This is how text selected when I press "shift+alt+right" twice:



Not good.
UPDATE: Oh, this doesn't work for this language. Hmmm.
I thought it is language-independent...

I just googled the question title and useful-looking results came up. For example, have you read this question? Select all text between quotes in VS Code? Some answers recommend extension Quick and Simple Text Selection but I haven't tried it myself. Please include what research you've done in your question. See [ask] for more on that and other tips.

Another one: how do you select only the entire string in vscode?

Of course, I read it
